# MS Access 3 conditions in a query?

Tags: iif

I have a total column that ranges from -7 to 7. I want to recode them in a `grand total` variable so everything under 0 is now 0, 1 stays 1, 2 stays 2, and 3 and everything above just stays 3. I am stuck on how to include a third condition.

This is the code I have which makes everything above 3 a 3, and keeps 1's and 2's as is. But I do not know how to make all negative numbers become a 0.

```
GrandTotal: IIf([total]>=3,3,[total])
```

Answer (score 0):

chained condition, try this:

```
GrandTotal: IIf([total]<0;0;IIf([total]>=3;3;[total]))
```